# Hiding the s4-titlerow Div will not have any effect on my team & community site

Tags: 2013, master-page, page-layout, css, custom-masterpage

I need to remove the unused white space from my team site and my community site, I added a custom CSS which have the following :-

```
div#s4-titlerow{ 
display: none;
}
```

But still the s4-titlerow is displayed as shown in the below picture:-

So is there a way to remove the un-used space and shift all the content to occupy it.
Second point I still need the search box to be shown ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using !important after your rule to override the inline style:

```
#s4-titlerow{ 
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: it worked well, but i have two questions. but what will !importnat do ? and is there a way to keep the search area , as when removing the s4-titlerow the search will be removed also ?

Comment: !important tells the browser that you think your rules is more important the rule of most specificity that is normally used in CSS. I think you should need some basic knowledge in CSS pal ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use !important before you have too!

I would use this instead

```
#s4-bodyContainer > #s4-titlerow {
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: While I applaud your attempt to not use !important, this did not actually work on my site.

Comment: @SouthShoreAK I've updated my answer because I had a typo. Try that again.